# copy full local Wordpress website from a computer to another

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, webmatrix

I have a wordpress website which is installed by Microsoft Webtrix on my computer A. 
I have installed Microsoft Webmatrix on my computer B so that I can continue my work on computer B so that I can continue work on computer B.
I want to copy my full wordpress website (website content + database) from computer A to B.

I can not find a tutorial which teaches how to copy database from computer A to B. 
I am totally new to creating web so please kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: Related: [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: can microsoft webmatrix do this job? or I have to do manually as stated in moving wordpress

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546856/how-to-export-wordpress-database-from-web-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Your best long term solution is to learn how to [export WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/) sites from local to local development environments as well as local to live host.

1. Within your present set up simply copy all files from wp-content of the site and transfer them to your new set up.
2. Add a plugin to your original site such as [WP Database Backup](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-database-backup/). This will allow you to dump the .sql (database) and keep a copy as a backup.
3. Over to the new set up (B computer). Create a new wordpress site.
4. Copy and paste the wp-content folder into the new site.
5. Now this is where you need to check with web matrix on your new set up. You'll need to make sure the wp-config.php file has the correct settings such as db name and password user etc.
6. Finally upload the backup db .sql file via the db plugin mentioned in step 2.