# how to Export wordpress database from web matrix

Tags: database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, webmatrix

I have WebMatrix version 1.  I made a WordPress site and now it's time to publish it. From what I've read, the best option is to publish the site from web matrix using the web deploy option. But my hosting (godaddy) doesn't support this feature. So I have to upload my site via FTP.

The problem is that I don't know how to export the databse from my webmatrix to my hosting.

From reading some posts, I think the best option is to use phpMyAdmin, but I couldn't install it on my computer.

Is that the easiest way to expot my database?

And if that is the best option, can anybody explain me how to install phpMyAdmin on my computer.

Thanks a lot

Gonzalo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/ to run phpmyadmin and export the database without actually installing phpmyadmin on your PC.