# migrate database from WebMatrix to 1and1 servers

Tags: mysql, wordpress, webmatrix, migrate

I have created a web site with WordPress and WebMatrix on my computer and now I want to have it live and hosted on 1&1's servers. I could transfer the files with ftp but not the database and its content. 
How do I extract the database from WebMatrix? Please note that the migrate button is not available for my MySql database !

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546856/how-to-export-wordpress-database-from-web-matrix

Answer (score 0):

You need to dump your database locally, and then run the resulting script up on your host via phpMyAdmin.  The easiest way to do this is by connecting to your local MySQL database and running mysqldump.  Check the database workspace in WebMatrix to get the name of your database (mine is wordpress960).  Then open a command prompt, and run the following command:

`mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > [database_name].sql`

After you have your *.sql file, you'll need to upload it to the database on your host.  Usually the cpanel on your host will provide some access via phpMyAdmin.  Here's a link that explains how to do the database restore:

http://web-kreation.com/tutorials/migrating-a-wordpress-site-ftp-phpmyadmin-and-sql-queries/

Hopefully this helps!