# How To Publish my Webmatrix WordPress install Locally to a LAMP host that does not support Web Deploy

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, webmatrix, webdeploy

I have been working on a WordPress plugin locally using IIS PHP and Wordpress installed through webmatrix.

So far.. Easy.  That is what I like.

But... Now I have to get the whole thing to my host that is not Using IIS and does now support Web Deploy.

FTPing the files is easy enough but I don't see how to get my MYSQL database up to the server.

What is the Easiest way to publish the database with the files?

And I need EASY!

:)
You guys are real programmers! Me not!

Comment: The easiest way would be to hire a programmer to do it for you :) Second easiest way is to ask your hosting provider to get everything done for you. Third (or perhaps this is second) easiest way is to find hosting provider that provides one click wordpress installer. There are probably some other ways, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22850458/1424639

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest answer is to move to a windows web host :-)

http://www.microsoft.com/web/hosting/home

If you're just working on a plugin, technically the plugin should be smart enough to create any data structures you need.  That's what makes the thing portable:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

You should be able to write the plugin to create any required data, then package and install the plugin on your site.

Happy coding!